# Change report's color in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Good morning!

Is possible or had some plugin to change color in the email sent through jenkins , is possible alter the color when project build is wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways to handle this:

1. **Set rules in your mail-client**, based on the subject of the email from Jenkins
   (should catch the 'fail' or 'success' in the subject)
2. Use the **[Email-ext Plugin*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)** to send different email-formats for 'Success' or 'Fail' - 
   just make sure you set the email-format to HTML
   (this will allow you to format the **body** of the message, in terms of colors, 
   or have a special indication in the subject for each case).

*) To set it with **Email-ext Plugin**, install it and then edit your jobs:
   Under '**Post-build Actions**' choose '**Editable Email Notification**' and then choose [**Advanced...**]
   to define different mail-templates for different situations
   (can also have different mail-lists for each case).

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand how do this. Because i install this plugin and dont see this option.

Comment: The documentation for the [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) says you can create custom "Jelly" templates and place them into the Jenkins home directory and use those when using the plugin. For specifying different templates in the job I believe you'll need to use the Advanced configuration for the plugin.

Comment: Ivo, Toby, under 'Post-build Actions' choose 'Editable Email Notification' and then choose [Advanced...] to define different mail-templates for different situations.

Comment: **Gonnen** can i configure with css or other this, but is other thing what?

Comment: Ivo, if you set the format of the mail (in the plugin) to be HTML, then you can edit the body of the message as you like - put a "style" block with CSS, use "font" or whatever works in HTML.